# Grid of JButtons Label

Tags: java, swing, grid, jbutton, chess

```
grid=new JButton[width][length];
for(y=0;y<length;y++){
    for(x=0;x<width;x++){
        final Border border=new LineBorder(Color.red, 5);
            grid[x][y]=new JButton(" ");
            grid[x][y].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                ((JButton)e.getSource()).setBorder(border);;
                System.out.println("Where do you want to move this piece");
            }
        });
        frame.add(grid[x][y]);

    }
}
grid[1][1]='R';
```

I am trying to get the first spot of the grid to say the letter R as in Rook; I am not sure how I can label specific JButton in a grid. Please help me... I am trying to make a GUI chess game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use methods instead of `=` to set component properties in `Swing`

```
grid[0][0].setText("R");
```

Answer (score 4):

This won't compile:

```
grid[1][1]='R';
```

Because you're trying to assign a char to a JButton. Instead understand that the grid holds JButtons, and call the JButton methods:

```
grid[0][0].setText("R");
```

Also, you don't want to do this:

```
System.out.println("Where do you want to move this piece");
```

It's a bad idea to combine println statements and GUI's (unless you're debugging). Rather, show that String in a JLabel.